# Cross linking applications in Symfony 2

Tags: symfony

There are a few tutorials on the web regarding the multi apps structure with Symfony 2, however I haven't seen any post on cross linking the apps (in term of http urls, how do you generate a link to the frontend blog post from your backend application?)

It's possible to put all the shared routes in a shared bundle, but then how do we generate the apps with the correct application path applied to it? For example, in my case I need to generate mysite.com/reset_password but since I do it from the backend I always get mysite.com/backend/reset_password. Of course I can trim the /backend/ out manually but that does not seem like the way to do it.

PS: I understand the downside of the multiple apps structure, however there are reason we want to use it.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know there is no built in way to do that, but it doesn't sound especially difficult to do.

Create a web service on the site you want to link to which provides URLs to specific locations.  You can then normalize these URLs to generic keys.  Then create an internal service to build a URL from this data.

Comment: Hi Flosculus, thank you for your suggestion. Can you please tell me more about what you meant by "normalize these URLs to generic keys"?

Comment: Like using DI to configure the URLs to a parameter.